# unknown comparison failure occurs with xtext formatter

Tags: formatting, comparison, dsl, xtext

I'm customizing the xtext formatter of my dsl and whist testing I get a weird comparison failure I don't understand.

Here's the relevant part of my grammar :

```
EisModel:
    'project' '=' project_name=STRING ';' 
    'plcname' '=' plc_name=STRING ';'
    'author' '=' author_name=STRING ';'
    testcases+=Testcase*;
Testcase:
    "testcase" testcase_name=ID '{'
    testblock=Testblock?
    '}';
Testblock:
    'testActive' '=' testActive=BoolConstant ';'
    'blockType' '=' blockType=BlockConstant ';'
    'description' '=' description=STRING ';'
    define=DefineBlock?;
BoolConstant:
    value=('true' | 'false');
BlockConstant:
    value=('FC' | 'FB');
```

And the comparison failure I get, I assume, has something to do with a problem regarding a terminal rule, since I am not doing anything extraorinary in the formatter.

This is the expected code of the JUnit failure trace:

```
74  4    S "true"               BoolConstant:value='true'
78  0    H
78  1    S ";"                  Testblock:(';'  )
79  2    H "\n\t"               Whitespace:TerminalRule'WS'
81  9    S "blockType"          Testblock:'blockType'
90  1    H " "                  Whitespace:TerminalRule'WS'
91  1    S "="                  Testblock:( '=' )
92  1    H " "                  Whitespace:TerminalRule'WS'
93  2    S "FC"                 BlockConstant:value='FC'
```

And this the actual code:

```
          B BoolConstant         Testblock:testActive=BoolConstant path:Testblock/testActive=Testcase/testblock=EisModel/testcases[0]
74  4     S "true"               BoolConstant:value='true'
          E BoolConstant         Testblock:testActive=BoolConstant path:Testblock/testActive=Testcase/testblock=EisModel/testcases[0]
78  0    H
78  1    S ";"                  Testblock:(';'  )
79  2    H "\n\t"               Whitespace:TerminalRule'WS'
81  9    S "blockType"          Testblock:'blockType'
90  1    H " "                  Whitespace:TerminalRule'WS'
91  1    S "="                  Testblock:( '=' )
92  1    H " "                  Whitespace:TerminalRule'WS'
          B BlockConstant        Testblock:blockType=BlockConstant path:Testblock/blockType=Testcase/testblock=EisModel/testcases[0]
93  2     S "FC"                 BlockConstant:value='FC'
          E BlockConstant        Testblock:blockType=BlockConstant path:Testblock/blockType=Testcase/testblock=EisModel/testcases[0]
```

The difference revolves around the lines 74 and 93.

And I don't know what is going wrong or even where I could tweak anything.
Could anyone please help?

Here's the test:

```
@Test def void testTestblock() {
    assertFormatted[
        toBeFormatted = '''
            project="proj";plcname="name";author="Bob"; 
            testcase One {testActive = true ; blockType = FC ;    
            description = "string" ;    }
        '''

        expectation = '''
            project = "proj";
            plcname = "name";
            author = "Bob";
            testcase One {
                testActive = true;
                blockType = FC;
                description = "string";
            }
        '''
    ]
}
```

The bug even occurs if I comment out my code in the formatter class which extends AbstractFormatter2, so I'll omit that here.

Comment: what do you actually test. could you provide a complete minimal grammar and testcase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sounds like a bug to me. please report it at https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core

workaround:

```
BoolConstant:
    value=BooleanValue;
BlockConstant:
    value=BlockValue;
BlockValue:"FC"|"FB";
BooleanValue: "true"|"false";
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, the workaround helped, but I've encountered a similar error a little bit down the road when continuing the formatting.

Comment: is that the same issue or a different one?

Comment: It is a different one regarding a different piece of my grammar. I'll post it.

Comment: could you help me understand why the workaround works?

Comment: No I don’t know

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little bit more of the grammar:

```
EisModel:
    'project' '=' project_name=STRING ';'
    'plcname' '=' plc_name=STRING ';'
    'author' '=' author_name=STRING ';'
    testcases+=Testcase*;

Testcase:
    "testcase" testcase_name=ID '{'
    testblock=Testblock?
    '}';

Testblock:
    'testActive' '=' testActive=BoolConstant ';'
    'blockType' '=' blockType=BlockConstant ';'
    'description' '=' description=STRING ';'
    define=DefineBlock?;

BoolConstant:
    value=BooleanValue;

BlockConstant:
    value=BlockValue;

BlockValue:
    'FC' | 'FB';

BooleanValue:
    'true' | 'false';

DefineBlock:
    'define' '{' direction=DirectionBlock '}' teststeps+=TeststepBlock*;

DirectionBlock:
    input=Input & inout=InOut? & output=Output;

Input:
    name='input' '[' inputVariables+=Variables* ']';

Output:
    name='output' '[' outputVariables+=Variables* ']';

InOut:
    name='inout' '[' inoutVariables+=Variables* ']';
```

And here another comparison failure.
expected:

```
123  5      S "input"              Input:name='input'
128  0      H
128  1      S "["                  Input:'['
129  0      H
129  1      S "]"                  Input:']'
130  0      H
130  6      S "output"             Output:name='output'
136  0      H
136  1      S "["                  Output:'['
137  0      H
137  1      S "]"                  Output:']'
```

actual:

```
        B Input'input'         DirectionBlock:input=Input path:DirectionBlock/input=DefineBlock/direction=Testblock/define=Testcase/testblock=EisModel/testcases[0]
123  5       S "input"              Input:name='input'
128  0       H
128  1       S "["                  Input:'['
129  0       H
129  1       S "]"                  Input:']'
        E Input'input'         DirectionBlock:input=Input path:DirectionBlock/input=DefineBlock/direction=Testblock/define=Testcase/testblock=EisModel/testcases[0]
130  0      H
        B Output'output'       DirectionBlock:output=Output path:DirectionBlock/output=DefineBlock/direction=Testblock/define=Testcase/testblock=EisModel/testcases[0]
130  6       S "output"             Output:name='output'
136  0       H
136  1       S "["                  Output:'['
137  0       H
137  1       S "]"                  Output:']'
        E Output'output'       DirectionBlock:output=Output path:DirectionBlock/output=DefineBlock/direction=Testblock/define=Testcase/testblock=EisModel/testcases[0]
```

The differences are now around the lines 123-129 and 130-137.

### Edit

After activating the formatter within the editior, I received an error message which I don't understand. Maybe someone else does:

```
Message: 
    Unhandled event loop exception    

Exception Stack Trace:
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.get(RegularImmutableMap.java:123)
        at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.get(RegularImmutableMap.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccess.regionForEObject(NodeModelBasedRegionAccess.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccess.regionForEObject(NodeModelBasedRegionAccess.java:22)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.AbstractFormatter2.isInRequestedRange(AbstractFormatter2.java:358)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.AbstractFormatter2.shouldFormat(AbstractFormatter2.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.internal.FormattableDocument.format(FormattableDocument.java:186)
        at org.example.eis.formatting2.EisFormatter._format(EisFormatter.java:224)
        at org.example.eis.formatting2.EisFormatter.format(EisFormatter.java:346)
```

A look at the java classes:

```
223 protected void _format(final DirectionBlock directionblock, @Extension final IFormattableDocument document) {
224    document.<DirectionBlock>format(directionblock); 
225 }
```